# ModSecurity whitelist http methods global

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

is there a possibility to create a whitelisting rule for whitelisting all GET requests in phase 1?

My custom_rule file is working - I've tested various rules before, but I really don't know how to disable all rules for GET Requests.

Something like: 
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "GET" "phase:1,log,pass"

Answer (score 0):

Pass will just carry on to the next rule. You want to use [allow](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#allow):

Note you also probably do not want to bother logging this rule, and you should give it an id (mandatory for ModSecurity 2.7 and above):

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "GET" "phase:1,id:1000;nolog,allow"
```

Note also that allow doesn't work in DetectionOnly mode since it's a disruptive rule, which always stuck me as a bad way of going about this. So you have to force the rule engine on to make it work there.

I have the following rules to allow whitelisting of static content if that helps (will need to be tweaked to your particular env):

```
#Allow any GET & HEAD requests, where no parameters passed, for static content file types
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(GET|HEAD)$" "phase:1,id:'1000',chain,allow,nolog"
  SecRule &ARGS "@eq 0" "chain"
  SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME ".*\.(css|eot|gif|htm|html|jpeg|jpg|js|pdf|png|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$" "t:lowercase,ctl:ruleEngine=On"

#Allow any GET & HEAD requests, where no parameters passed, for default index files (e.g. /somepage/)
#except for dynamic content urls (which start with api or application):
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^(GET|HEAD)$" "phase:1,id:'1001',chain,allow,nolog"
  SecRule &ARGS "@eq 0" "chain"
  SecRule REQUEST_URI "/$" "chain"
  SecRule REQUEST_URI "!^/(api|application)" "t:lowercase,ctl:ruleEngine=On"
```

Let me know if you have any questions on these.